# Do i need a context.xml file to deploy spring webapp to tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat6

I am new to Tomcat, so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I have created a spring mvc webapp that currently runs locally using the maven-jetty-plugin.

I can successfully create the WAR file. I would like to deploy the WAR file into a tomcat6 instance. However, I am not sure if I need to create a context.xml file for tomcat? And if I do, where would I place the  file in my spring webapp? My current directory structure looks like this:

```
src
|
|-main
|  |-java
   |-resource
   |    |-META-INF
   |-webapp
   |    |-WEB-INF
            |-web.xml
```

Answer (score 5):

The `context.xml` file is used to configure application specific instructions for your container (tomcat).  For instance, you can define JNDI resources, loggers, valves, etc.  See [Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) for more details.

By default, Tomcat will auto-generate a default `context.xml` for your war if you do not specify one yourself and store it within its own configuration files in /conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/[context-root].xml

If you want to include it as part of your war, you can place it in /META-INF/context.xml within your war.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't.  The `context.xml` file is optional, and by no means required by Spring.

`context.xml` is used to configure Tomcat itself. The defaults are sensible, there's no need to override them unless you have a good reason.